# Sorting Decimals in Show-ListView

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm wondering how one would sort a column of decimal or currency values numerically in show-listview?

A contrived example:

```
$decimalArray = 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0

$props = @{
        Title = "Decimal Sorting"
        InfoTitle = "Decimal Sorting"
        InfoDescription = "Decimal Sorting"
        PageSize = 100000
    }
$decimalArray | Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label = "Decimals"; Expression={$_}},
    @{Label = "Currency"; Expression={"{0:c}" -f $_}},
    @{Label = "Number"; Expression={"{0:n0}" -f $_}}
Close-Window
```

In the example above:

1. The first column is a decimal
2. The second column is currency
3. The third column is an integer

Only the integer sorts numerically. It seems as soon as a decimal or currency symbol is added to the value, ListView treats the data as a string.

Might I sort decimals and currency numerically?

Thank you,
vic

Answer (score 1):

Spe uses the class `ListViewComparer` to handle the sorting. It appears as of 6.1 it sorts `DateTime`, `int`, and finally `string`.

You can submit a feature request or a pull request if you would like to see more datatypes covered.

```
public int Compare(String str1, String str2)
{
    DateTime dateTime1, dateTime2;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(str1, out dateTime1) && DateTime.TryParse(str2, out dateTime2))
    {
        return DateTime.Compare(dateTime1, dateTime2);
    }

    int int1, int2;
    if (int.TryParse(str1, out int1) && int.TryParse(str2, out int2))
    {
        if (int1 < int2)
            return -1;
        return int1 > int2 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return String.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

### Update

This should be included in 6.2. See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1195) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael.